# Iterate elements in BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT struct?

Tags: c++, iterator, boost-fusion

Is there anyways to fusion::for_each() to iterate through a1 and a2 in a BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT or BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ASSOC_ADT, just like if adapted using BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT?

```
class A
{
private:
    int a1_;
    double a2_;

public:
    void set_a1(int v) { a1_ = v; }
    int get_a1() const { return a1_; }

    void set_a2(double v) { a2_ = v; }
    double get_a2() const { return a2_; }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ASSOC_ADT(
    A,
    (int, int, obj.get_a1(), obj.set_a1(val) )
    (double, double, obj.get_a2(), obj.set_a2(val) )
)

struct Print 
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()( T& t ) const
    {
        // T is of type adt_attribute_proxy
        // cout << ??
        // would like to print a1 and a2 value
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    boost::fusion::for_each( a, Print() );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`adt_attribute_proxy`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/notes.html#fusion.notes.adt_attribute_proxy) provides method `get` to access attribute value.

```
struct Print
{

    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T& t) const
    {
        std::cout << t.get();
    }
};
```

P.S. There are errors in you sample `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ASSOC_ADT` macro. Each element should be declared with 5 params (`attribute_typeN`, `attribute_const_typeN`, `get_exprN`, `set_exprN`, `key_typeN`) Maybe you mix up BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ASSOC_ADT with BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT?

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe the answer is such simple call.  I looked at this [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/notes.html#fusion.notes.adt_attribute_proxy) but wasn't able to understand that was it.

Comment: sorry, then is there a way to get the type of t.get()?  I see "proxy_typeN::type" in the doc.  But can't understand...

Comment: there are 2 specialization of `adt_attribute_proxy` for non-const sequence (in doc it referenced as `proxy_typeN`) and for const sequence (`const_proxy_typeN`). They both have current attribute type (`proxy_typeN::type` and `const_proxy_typeN::type`), `get` method (`proxyN.get()` and `const_proxyN.get()`). Difference between them is that only `proxy_typeN` has `operator =` (`proxyN=t`)